# How to detect WiFi spoofing?

Tags: wifi, spoofing

I have recently become concerned that someone might be spoofing the WiFi network at my office. The network has been really unstable these last few weeks. The password isn't really that secret, and I'm guessing that if someone had the SSID as well as the password, someone could configure a fake router with the same MAC advertisting the same SSID and password. Is that possible?
Are there any tools for Windows that can be used to see if there is an unsual amount of broadcasts for an SSID with the same MAC? Or are there other ways to detect this?

Comment: You are exactly talking about "Evil Twin Attack" , I think. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_twin_(wireless_networks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, Wifi spoofing is named as Evil Twin attack. You can find more information about it if you search as "Evil Twin Attack" rather than "Wifi Spoofing". 
I have found a good article about the attack: [What is evil twin?](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/evil-twin).
Plus, there is a good explanation about how to commit it on [Null-Byte.WonderHowTo](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-creating-evil-twin-wireless-access-point-eavesdrop-data-0147919/). ( for learning purpose only ).

There is no need the attacker to know about your password. In addition, he does not even need to spoof your MAC address. Detecting Evil Twin is already explained well in [How would you detect an Evil Twin attack, especially in a new environment?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85138/how-would-you-detect-an-evil-twin-attack-especially-in-a-new-environment) . So you can read it.